# How to edit_*_path without specific id? Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

first of all: I'm new to ruby on rails.

I want to link to an empty "edit" site. For example: I'm clicking on the link "Edit Content". I should be directed to "contents/edit" but without any values in the form. Than i should be able to select the "Content" by clicking on an entry in a html select box.. after that the form should be filled with the contents values.

I tried to modify the "edit_content_path" method but there is always an ID needed.

any ideas?

what i've read to find a solution: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

greetings! =)

Answer (score 0):

You can only 'edit' an existing object. You need to use new_content_path to be able to create content.

Rails by default gives you 7 RESTful actions.

[image]

Please refer to ruby.railstutorial.org/book?version=3.2#top for good details.

Comment: there is no way to add another action? if not, i have to rethink my page layout..

Comment: oh yes you can always add any number of actions you want. Rails by default gives you these actions.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following to the `resources :contents` call in your `routes.rb`:

```rb
resources :contents, :except => :edit do
  get 'edit', :on => :collection
end
```

Comment: and the link is the same without "tree" in brackets? link_to 'Edit', edit_tree_path(tree)

Comment: Or you can use a singleton resource (ie. resource :content)

Comment: @tjschuu, creating the route in this way will create a `edit_contents_path` helper method (without an argument).

Comment: @sailor, interesting. I had never used that before. That looks like it would work if the op wants all actions to behave that way.